# SQLAlchemy_utils error: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, anaconda, sqlalchemy-utils

Importing `sqlalchemy_utils` package by doing

```
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import create_database
```

gives an error message

> /Users/x/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi.
>     """)

I have tried updating `sqlalchemy_utils` package using `pip` but it appears that the latest published package is already installed.

```
$ pip install sqlalchemy_utils
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy_utils in /Users/x/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.34.2)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy>=1.0 in /Users/x/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sqlalchemy_utils) (1.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/x/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sqlalchemy_utils) (1.12.0)
```

How can we fix this problem? Will doing the update as suggested cause problems when updating `sqlalchemy_utils` in the future?

Comment: What does `psycopg2.__version__` return?

Comment: @GordThompson `2.7.6.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)`

Comment: Okay, so you are getting a "UserWarning" (not an error) alerting you to the packaging change that took place with the release of version 2.8. Does that warning prevent your code from running?

Comment: @GordThompson It does not prevent the code from running. Do you suggest performing a fix to remove the warning, or ignoring it for now?